# Get MySQLValue by column name using mysql-haskell

Tags: mysql, haskell

I'm using the [mysql-haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mysql-haskell-0.8.1.0) package. I want to write my query and then get each value from a row by column name. But I'm having trouble putting the pieces together.

[Here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mysql-haskell-0.8.1.0/docs/Database-MySQL-Base.html#v:queryStmt) is the query function I am using.

```
queryStmt :: MySQLConn -> StmtID -> [MySQLValue] -> IO ([ColumnDef], InputStream [MySQLValue])
```

This is my current code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Main where

import Database.MySQL.Base
import Data.Binary.Get
import qualified System.IO.Streams as Streams
import Data.Word
import Data.Traversable

main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo {ciUser = "ffxi_auction_house", ciDatabase = "darkstar" }
  s <- prepareStmt conn "SELECT itemid FROM item_armor WHERE name = ?"
  (def:defs, is) <- queryStmt conn s [MySQLText "moogle_suit"]
  armorStreams <- Streams.toList is
  armors <- forM armorStreams $ \(MySQLInt16U value:_) -> return ItemArmor { itemid = value }
  print armors

data ItemArmor = ItemArmor
  {
    itemid :: !Word16
  } deriving (Show)
```

The querystmt returns the list of columns a matrix of data.
This actually works but I have to rely on the order of the return set.

There is one function called [getTextField](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mysql-haskell-0.8.1.0/docs/Database-MySQL-Protocol-MySQLValue.html#v:getTextField) I keep looking at but I can't figure out how it fits.

```
getTextField :: ColumnDef -> Get MySQLValue
```

Comment: What does "can't figure out" mean? What did you try to make it fit? Did you read the docs of `binary`? Even if you parse the result, you still have to pattern match on a list (so you still rely on the order) of values, and for each value, you have to pattern match on the constructor for the appropriate SQL type. Everything about this package seems to treat a table as a sequence of columns (as opposed to a set, which is the interpretation you want) - this is probably done for performance reasons. The package simply doesn't offer this functionality (probably by design).

Comment: What do you think "Can't figure out" means? What I've tried doing is seeing a path forward by reading the docs before I start coding. Thanks for the rest of your answer though seems like you might be right.

Comment: I don't know what "can't figure out" means - hence the question. It could be mean you spent ten hours hacking trying to figure it out, and couldn't; or you looked at the type signature and decided you couldn't figure it out. To rephrase my question: what is your existing knowledge regarding how `getTextField` (or any other part of this package) could be used to solve your problem?

Comment: I couldn't look at the type signature and understand what it's supposed to return. The Get function doesn't have a type Show and I don't know what it's used for. I think it's a red herring though, so probably not worth going down the rabbit hole if it's not going to help me query the value by column name. I'm wondering if I can zip both headers and values together and create a helper function myself to return the data I want.